# Puppeteer selector based on attribute error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to select input based on `type` equal to `'submit'`. Why does this selector not work?

```
await page.click('input[type="submit"')
```

For:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

It's a typical selector in j@uery.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `it won't work`?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to wait for the element specified by the selector to be added to the DOM and visible before attempting to click it:

```
await page.waitForSelector('input[type="submit"]', {
  visible: true,
});
```

Additionally, as AJC24 pointed out, you are in fact missing a right square bracket `]`, so the selector must be accurate before passing it to `page.click()`:

```
await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo in your selector to me. It should be:

```
await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
```

You were missing the `]` character at the end of your selector.